# Java: SortedSet "cursor"-style iterator

Tags: java, iterator, set

I need to iterate both forwards and backwards in a sorted set. If I use [NavigableSet](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html), I get a strictly-forward iterator and a strictly-backward iterator (`iterator()` and `descendingIterator()`) but none that can move forward and backward.

What's the time complexity of `NavigableSet.lower()` and `higher()` ? I can use those instead, but am reluctant to do so if they are inefficient.

Comment: Have you (time)tested the alternatives with a representative dataset?

Comment: you have a point -- if you have to optimize, you ought to be prepared to measure -- but that's why I asked here, to gain wisdom from those of you who are more experienced. (not to mention it should be in the documentation but isn't. grrrr.)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your exact needs you could convert the sorted set to a list, say an array list, and use a [list iterator](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) for traversal. It can be used in both directions via the [next()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#next()) and [previous()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous()) methods, which may be mixed freely.

Comment: This is a fair point, and a better description of usage would help.  However, at least as far as those bundled with the Java API, the only options for SortedSet (TreeSet, ConcurrentSkipListSet) are also NavigableSets.  So there would just be the added time of converting to a list, and then the procedure as specified by Andy in the comment to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two implementations of the NavigableSet.  Saying you opted for the TreeSet, while I don't have the source handy, the Javadoc says that it is based on a [TreeMap providing O(log(n)) for get/put/containsKey/remove](http://objectissues.blogspot.com/2006/11/big-o-notation-and-java-constant-time.html).  At worst this would perform one get to find the value of we're finding the lower/higher for, plus an additional search to get the next/previous value, providing O(2log(n)) = O(log(n)).

Trees are worst case O(n) for search in the event it is actually a list, but in general,  O(height).

Comment: are there trees which are faster for iteration between adjacent elements?

Comment: It's a trade-off between operations. It depends on the size of `n`. For a tree, get is `O(log n)`, and iteration is also `O(log n)`. Using a sorted array/list, get is `O(n)`, and iteration is `O(1)`.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'm pretty sure SkipLists have O(log n) get, and O(1) iteration.